# Getting a Unable to import 'folium' error, not sure what to do

Tags: python, python-3.x

folium won't install for me and I am unsure of what to do. I am still new to python. I tried:
pip install folium,
pip3 install folium
easy_install folium

I downloaded the github folium clone and put it in the site-packages for my python, cd'd there and ran python setup.py install.

```
import folium 

map = folium.Map(location=[37.8,-122.3])
```

None of this worked! Not sure what to do but I am going to have to give up on this tutorial for the moment. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did `pip3 install folium` give some error messages?

Comment: @ex4 It says it installed successfully

Comment: And you use Python3? Remember that command `python` opens Python2 console.